# newline character in comm perl script

Tags: perl, comm

There is a newline character getting inserted between the 2 filenames. 
How do I avoid this?

```
$diff = `comm -3 "/tmp/${PATH1U}_${SITE1}_s_${USER} /tmp/${PATH2U}_${SITE2}_s_${USER}"|wc -l`;
```

This is the error message while executing:

> comm: missing operand after `/tmp/file1\n /tmp/file2\n'

Comment: `chomp` the filenames after reading them.

Answer (score 4):

Two problems:

- `$USER`'s value ends with a newline. You can [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) it away. Fix:

  ```
  chomp($USER);
  ```
- You are passing one very long and incorrect path instead of two. Fix:

  ```
  `comm -3 '/tmp/${PATH1U}_${SITE1}_s_${USER}' '/tmp/${PATH2U}_${SITE2}_s_${USER}' | wc -l`
  ```

  But that's a hackish way of creating shell literals. Cleaner:

  ```
  use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

  my $comm_cmd = shell_quote('comm', '-3',
     "/tmp/${PATH1U}_${SITE1}_s_${USER}",
     "/tmp/${PATH2U}_${SITE2}_s_${USER}");

  `$comm_cmd | wc -l`
  ```